# Unable to run npm install on centos7 VPS server

Tags: centos, node.js

I want to update my node.js project dependencies on VPS server(CentOS7).

I run this command for updating the dependencies:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs16/bin/npm install
```

but it gives me this message:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you installed node? It looks like you have not. Show the output of `type -a node`

Comment: Yes, it installed by host provider.

Comment: Try: `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`